# Modified .cab file causes installer to throw error 1334

Tags: windows-installer, cab, toshiba-stack

I had an old version of Toshiba Bluetooth stacks for Windows for non-Toshiba hardware, and I needed to update it.

The new versions of this software will only support Toshiba hardware unless device info, UID etc. is added to the inf file prior to install. But the inf is in a .cab file but after Extracting & Repacking the cab and trying to install, it throws `error 1334`.

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Have you tried updating the driver for the device via Device Manager, then browsing and pointing to the INF file?

Comment: Yes and it says data of this type is unsupported when windows tries to use it :/

Answer (score 0):

1334 means that you need to:

1. Troubleshoot the file paths in the `.cab` file:

> The file '[2]' cannot be installed because the file cannot be found in cabinet file '[3]'. This could indicate a network error, an error reading from the CD-ROM, or a problem with this package.

2. Update the file table of the `.msi` package:

> The above error occurs only when the packaged merge module contains more than one file.
>
> To avoid this either keep the sequence same during creating of localized MSI or manually edit the transform after using msitrans.exe. If the file table has large number of entries then you may export file table from base MSI package and import it in localized MSI package

**References**

- [Error 1334. The file ‘_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx’ cannot be installed because the file cannot be found in cabinet file – Microsoft Visual Studio/.Net Framework Setup & Deployment Tips & Tricks](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsnetsetup/2012/11/28/error-1334-the-file-_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-cannot-be-installed-because-the-file-cannot-be-found-in-cabinet-file/)
- [Windows Installer Error Messages (Windows)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372835)
- [Installer Database Reference | Database Tables | File Table (Windows)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368596)
- [System Error Codes (1300-1699) (Windows)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681385)
- [INFO: WinInet Error Codes (12001 through 12156)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/193625/info-wininet-error-codes-12001-through-12156)