# How to edit InstallShield .cab without triggering error -5005 : 0x8007000d

Tags: windows, editing, installshield, cab

```
How to edit InstallShield .cab without triggering error -5005 : 0x8007000d?
```

Did i miss a step?

**user_Setup.exe** File version: 9.1.0.429

Issue:
Need to remove an exe inside InstallShield.exe, **user_Setup.exe**.
i have the source file but it is very outdated. Already lost the .ism files used to build the current InstallShield.exe, **user_Setup.exe**

Used Universal Extractor to get InstallShield .cab files and other files (**setup.exe** included). 
Before i edit the .cab file, I can run **setup.exe** without triggering any error. Then I use iscab.exe to edit the .cab file.
When I run **setup.exe**, it immediately prompt:

```
An error (-5005 : 0x8007000d) has occurred while running the setup.

Detail>>  

Error Message:  
Error Code: -5005 : 0x8007000d  
Error Information:  
>Kernel\KernelMedia.cpp (95)  
>Kernel\KernelMedia.cpp (95)  
>SetupDLL\SetupDLL.cpp (1619)
```

If edit setup.ini, CheckMD5=Y to CheckMD5=N, the same error message appears.

**Edit InstallShield .cab**
Steps taken:

1. Place iscab.exe in C:\Program Files\InstallShield\2010\System
2. Launch cmd.exe
3. List all file groups and files in cabfile to inifile, allfiles.ini
   iscab.exe C:\Users\user\Desktop\Test\user_Setup\Disk1\data1.cab -i"allfiles.ini" -lx
4. Remove files listed in the inifile, removefiles.ini
   iscab.exe C:\Users\user\Desktop\Test\user_Setup\Disk1\data1.cab -i"removefiles.ini" -r
5. Error message appear when run setup.exe
6. Restore data1.cab with original .cab
7. Replace one existing file listed in the inifile, replacefiles.ini in order to troubleshoot
   iscab.exe C:\Users\user\Desktop\Test\user_Setup\Disk1\data1.cab -i"replacefiles.ini" -a
8. Generate inifile, replacefiles.ini and the compare the contents with allfiles.ini
   Both inifile contents are matching
9. Same error message with step 5 appear when run **setup.exe**
10. Edit setup.ini, CheckMD5=Y to CheckMD5=N
11. Same error message with step 5 appear when run **setup.exe**

Edit 20181109 PM1330 harrymc

**Convert .exe files into a project file**
Steps taken:

1. Open and Edit **setup.exe** files using InstallShield
   File | Open...
   File name: *
   Open As: Auto or Wizard
   Select **setup.exe**
2. Error message appear:
   InstallShield cannot open C:\Users\user\Desktop\Test\user_Setup\Disk1\setup.exe.
   Please contact Acresso technical support for more information.
3. Open and Edit **user_Setup.exe** files using InstallShield
   File | Open...
   File name: *
   Open As: Auto or Wizard
   Select **user_Setup.exe**
4. Error message appear:
   InstallShield cannot open C:\Users\user\Desktop\Test\user_Setup.exe.
   Please contact Acresso technical support for more information.
5. Open and Edit **Start.exe** files using InstallShield
   File | Open...
   File name: *
   Open As: Auto or Wizard
   Select **Start.exe**
6. Error message appear:
   InstallShield cannot open C:\Users\user\Desktop\Start.exe.
   Please contact Acresso technical support for more information.

Reference:
[Universal Extractor](https://www.legroom.net/software/uniextract)
[How do I extract an InstallShield Cabinet file?](https://superuser.com/questions/88645/how-do-i-extract-an-installshield-cabinet-file)
[How to update an InstallShield v6.x CAB file](https://shieldmaster.wordpress.com/2012/01/17/how-to-update-an-installshield-v6-x-cab-file/)
[Modified .cab file causes installer to throw error 1334](https://superuser.com/questions/491651/modified-cab-file-causes-installer-to-throw-error-1334)
[I Didn’t Know InstallShield Could Do That?](https://blogs.flexera.com/installtalk/2011/02/i-didnt-know-installshield-could-do-that/)

Extra Info:
By using Universal Extractor from LegRoom.net,
 i will get the following files/folders:

Disk1 (Folder)
    |- data1.cab    (File)
    |- data1.hdr    (File)
    |- data2.cab    (File)
    |- engine32.cab (File)
    |- layout.bin   (File)
    |- setup.exe    (File)
    |- setup.ibt    (File)
    |- setup.ini    (File)
    |- setup.inx    (File)

Content of removefiles.ini:

[ISCAB Info]
Product=ISCAB
Version=2.0

[Tools]
File10="common\nircmdc.exe"
File58="Tools\common\nircmdc.exe"

[Language Independent OS Independent Files]
File2="nircmdc.exe"

Content of replacefiles.ini:

[ISCAB Info]
    Product=ISCAB
    Version=2.0

[AdminScripts]
    File6="user.bat"

Content of setup.ini:

[Startup]
    AppName=user_Setup
    ProductGUID=DD1111D1-1D11-111D-1DDD-D11111111D1D
    CompanyName=user
    CompanyURL=https://superuser.com
    ErrorReportURL=http://www.installshield.com/isetup/ProErrorCentral.asp?ErrorCode=%d : 0x%x&ErrorInfo=%s
    MediaFormat=1
    LogMode=1
    Resource=_Setup.dll
    SmallProgress=N
    SplashTime=5
    CheckMD5=Y
    CmdLine=
    ShowPasswordDialog=N
    EngineVersion=9.1.0.429
    EngineBinding=1
    [Languages]
    Default=0x0009
    count=1
    key0=0x0009

Comment: Try this: Start InstallShield, menu File / Open, type `*` into the FileName field and hit enter, select the setup exe file, and see if InstallShield will convert it to a project.

Comment: Tried to open and edit setup.exe files using InstallShield.
I get the error, InstallShield cannot open C:\Users\user\Desktop\Test\user_Setup.exe. Please contact Acresso technical support for more information.

Comment: So that's what you need to do : [link](https://www.flexera.com/products/installation/installshield-support.html).

Comment: Could you post the solution here as answer? The link requires registration as a member.

Comment: Done as requested. Please share your experience with InstallShield Support with us, for future readers of this post.

Answer (score 0):

In many cases, InstallShield may be able to convert a created menu setup file
back to a project that can be modified and re-generated.

This is done in the menu *File / Open*, specifying `*` in the FileName field
and hit enter, then selecting the setup `exe` file.

In the case of the poster, this resulted in the error

> InstallShield cannot open `C:\Users\user\Desktop\Test\user_Setup.exe`. Please contact Acresso technical support for more information.

Acresso technical support can be contacted through the the page of
[InstallShield Technical Support and FAQs](https://www.flexera.com/products/installation/installshield-support.html).